# Internet-radio stream using ExoPlayer v2

Tags: android, streaming, audio-streaming, exoplayer

I used `EXOPlayer v1.5.6` to playing  `Mp3/AAC` AudioStream, but this version a has lot of flaws.

I decided to upgrade to `v 2.0.2`, but I can't find documentation for playing only Audio Stream. 
Please, help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the developer guide for new version of ExoPlayer - [link](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html).

You can play stream from URI this way:

```
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(
    new Handler(),
    new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(
        new DefaultBandwidthMeter()
    )
);
mediaPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
    getApplicationContext(),
    trackSelector,
    new DefaultLoadControl()
);
MediaSource source = new ExtractorMediaSource(
    yourURI,
    new OkHttpDataSourceFactory(
        new OkHttpClient(),
        userAgent,
        null
    ),
    new DefaultExtractorsFactory(),
    null,
    null
);
mediaPlayer.prepare(source);
mediaPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: Could you point out what function exactly in this causes it to stream directly rather than download and play? I'm just curious.